# The same XPaths - different results

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

```
$str = '
<body>
<table><tr><td><b class="1">1</b></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td><b class="2">1</b></td></tr></table>
<p>some text</p>
</body>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//table[//b[contains(@class, "2")]]') as $i) 
   print_r($i);

echo "------------------------------------------\n";

foreach($xpath->query('//table//b[contains(@class, "2")]/ancestor::table') as $i) 
   print_r($i);
```

The first XPath selects both tables while the second one gets only the target (second) table. Why?

[test on eval.in](https://eval.in/516253)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in your XPath predicate `[//b...]`. It should be `[.//b...]` instead.

Explanation:
`[...]` are predicates, they only act as filters. When you say `a[b]`, you select all `a` nodes which satisfy the predicate `[b]`. In case `a` and `b` are elements, it would, from the current context node, select all `a` elements which contain a `b` element as a child element.

- `//b` is an `AbbreviatedAbsoluteLocationPath` and selects all `b` element nodes in the entire document. Both tables are in a document with a `b` element that qualifies, therefore the predicate `[//b]` is always true for your document, no matter where you apply it.
- `.//b` is an `AbbreviatedRelativeLocationPath` and selects all `b` element nodes which are descendants (children and their children, recursively). The predicate `[.//b]` will only be true for `table` elements which have a descendant element `b`.

Step path expressions like `//b` or `.//b`, when used as predicates like `[//b]` or `[.//b]`, are *true* if the nodeset selected by the step path expression is not empty.

The predicate applied doesn't change anything about that, because of the `//b` instead of `.//b`:
`//b[contains(@class, "2")]` selects all be elements in the entire document that contain "2" in their `class` attribute. You're basically performing a check on the document, not the tree below your desired `table` element, and that document check is satisfied for both `table` elements because both are in a document which contains a `b` element that has "2" in its `class` attribute.

Comment: 1) you can look to eval demo 2) your explanation is not qutly correct. In the 1st case its enough to be b[contains] in any place of the document. But thanks any way

Comment: Why is the second query wrong? It seems correct to me: first it selects all (two) `table` elements in the document; for each of them selects all `b` descendants (one per table); then for each of them tests `@class` attribute; the predicate turns out true for one of them; for that `b` element the last step expression returns its `ancestor:table`. Am I wrong in my interpretation? Here is [eval.in fork](https://eval.in/516425) with text nodes modified to distinguish between `table` elements returned.

Comment: @CiaPan The inner selections are just predicates. The `/ancestor::table` path is applied to the selected `table` element nodes. From their perspective, there are no ancestor `table` elements.With the `ancestor-or-self::` axis, things would be different.

Comment: @CiaPan *Why is the second query wrong?* the secont is true

Comment: @CiaPan To my best knowledge, that XPath engine in the link that you've specified is broken.

Comment: @ChristianHujer and what about this engine - http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/34b32896a78f9e0166dfc7808718cf63

Comment: @splash58 This one gets this right, for a `<doc>` with two `<table>` elements like yours and your second XPath it correctly returns zero nodes.

Comment: @ChristianHujer The 'inner selection' **//b** in the second query `//table//b[...]/ancestor::table` is not a predicate; it's a step in the path expression. A predicate is `[contains(...)]` expression, which filters some of `b` elements.

Comment: @CiaPan wrapped `b` in `[b]` where I was speaking of a predicate. Any other location where you think it's unclear?

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, you are right. The second of the OP's expressions (`//table//b[contains(@class, "2")]/ancestor::table`) will only select one of the `table` elements - the wanted one. Christian, you are wrong about this: `/ancestor::table` is not applied to a `table` element, but to a `b` element. The second expression should not return two elements - if it does, **then** your implementation is broken. (I think you simply confused `//table[//b[contains(@class, "2")]]/ancestor::table` with ``//table//b[contains(@class, "2")]/ancestor::table``.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Ah right I misread the second OP's expression as `//table[//b[contains(@class, "2")]]/ancestor::table` - and that quite consistently! I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Here's is another example, with XML data slightly different from OP's, so it's a bit easier to identify the objects returned. One can replace '2' with '1' before clicking 'Test' to see how results vary. (I've prepared that yesterday but got away from internet and could not post until now.)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to paste the link. :( Here it is: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8ee8119a976954d75866561a4580a7be

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer corrects the mistake, but does not really explain why the original path expression went wrong.

Your first expression looks like:

```
//table[//b[contains(@class, "2")]]
```

It has two *predicates*, one nested inside the other:

```
//table[//b[contains(@class, "2")]]
           ^---------------------^       inner predicate
       ^--------------------------^      outer predicate
```

Think of predicates as filters that are applied to the left context of the predicate. In the extreme cases, either none or all of the intermediate result nodes are discarded by such a predicate.

Each intermediate result node is only kept if the predicate to its right evaluates to `true`. In the case of the inner predicate:

```
//b[contains(@class, "2")]
```

`//b` yields a set of intermediate `b` element nodes (all `b` element nodes in the entire document) that are then filtered by the predicate `[contains(@class, "2")]`. Given your input XML document, the expression inside the predicate only returns `true` for *one* of the `b` elements.

But `//b[contains(@class, "2")]` in turn serves as the content of the outer predicate:

```
//table[outer predicate]
```

Now `//table` selects as an intermediate result all `table` element nodes in the entire document, and for each of them, the expression inside the predicate is checked.

**Importantly, the outer predicate `//b[contains(@class, "2")]` will return `true` for *both* `table` elements. This is because for both of them it is true that somewhere in the entire document, there is a `b` element whose `class` attribute contains `2`.**

What you actually wanted to do is: evaluate the outer predicate expression from the perspective of each `table` element - and the accepted answer shows how to do that. Namely, using `.//` instead of `//` in the predicate.

Comment: Thank for explanation/ I tried to say this in the 2nd point of my comment in hope that the answerer improve the text. :)